# How nutty are the terms "nut case", "health nut" and "sports nut"?

Tags: etymology, slang, pejorative-language

If someone is ***nuts about something/someone*** it means they are a very enthusiastic— sometimes bordering on obsessive—devotee of that particular thing or person. **To be nuts** is a colloquial term meaning *crazy*, *mad* or *insane*, and there is the idiomatic expression ***to drive someone nuts***, meaning a person's annoying or irritating behaviour is responsible for making another, figuratively speaking, lose their mind.

- When (and why) did the humble innocuous fruit, *[nut](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nut)*, become associated with insanity?
- We're all familiar with the politically incorrect term, *[basket case](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/basket_case)*, I am referring to  its modern-day meaning: *someone or something that is incapable of functioning normally, a state of helplessness [...], most frequently in the context of mental health*, is the idiom
  ***nut case*** therefore related to that expression or is it coincidental?
- Are the terms **health nut** and **sports nut** derogatory, neutral or positive today? Were they originally insults, as I suspect, or were they meant to be semi-affectionate, tongue-in-cheek expressions?

Comment: You could probably split this into two questions: (1) Etymology of nut meaning insanity and (2) are health nut or sports nut derogatory. The two questions aren't really answered through the same means.

Comment: @MrHen I could, I'm aware that asking multiple questions can be problematic, but I disagree that *health nut* and *sports nut* are unrelated to nut=insanity.  If I did split the two, my fear is that (2) will be closed as POB, and I am really interested in those terms, as I believe "sports fan" is neutral, whereas the term, "health fan" does not exist, which i find curious.

Comment: I would say that the tongue-in-cheek aspect of sports/health nut has always predominated from its inception and has been a self-naming as much as a pejorative.

Comment: Both *nut* and *fan[atic]* seem to me somewhat derogatory (or self-deprecating, as the case may be) as implying a departure from the ideal of moderation, *aurea mediocritas,* Μηδὲν ἄγαν.

Comment: ...and don't forget the other "nut" expression, "He's off his nut!" :-)

Comment: You know, *fruits* aren’t always that well looked upon either. :)

Comment: I'd say they're neutral (Britain) - could swing pos/neg with context, tone.

Comment: related [What's the case in "basket case"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138640/whats-the-case-in-basket-case)

Comment: I never knew, and still would not know, and will never know, that *basket case* is politically incorrect.

Comment: @BlessedGeek read this article on [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2012/jun/01/mind-your-language-basket-case). Seeing is believing.

Comment: They're nutty like a fruitcake. :P

Comment: I would add that the slang term "nutter" is a really quite rude term for a mentally ill person in Britain, but not used in Canada or the United States to my knowledge.

Comment: Marilou, should we put all our cases into the basket of one newspaper? While the phrase is still prevalently used?

Comment: @BlessedGeek it's not the newspaper at blame, but its readers who were offended by the term.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Nut* is slang for *head.*  And *nut case* means *head case*; i.e, mind/brain injury/illness.

It's a pretty obvious metaphor: nuts and human heads have breakable covers, are spherical living things, and are filled with other important living things (some of which may even resemble one another -- compare walnut meats with brain hemispheres visually, for instance).

*Nut case*, in turn, results in the adjective *nuts*, meaning 'crazy'. Then, by comparison, *crazy about `X`* becomes *nuts about `X`*; and someone who is nuts about `X` is of course an *`X` nut*.

Comment: Status update, as they say on facebook: I just noticed that [this is my 900th answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler?tab=answers&sort=newest). The party will start at 8; byob.

Comment: +1 I *do* like the walnut/brain folds analogy. And **cheers**!

Comment: When did "nut" change from referring to the holder of our big brain to the holder of our little one? :)

Comment: @Barmar: It never changed. It's both. Haven't you noticed the way men think?

Answer (score 5):

Etymology shows  that *nut* as a noun  was first associated with insanity at the beginning of the 20th century, but as an adjective (nuts) it was used since 1846.  Also the *nut-case* is first attested in 1959 that is much later than the origin of *basket case*. It appears there is no clear relation between the two expressions.

[nut](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Nut&searchmode=none) n.

> Meaning "crazy person, crank" is attested from 1903 (British form nutter first attested 1958; *nut-case is from 1959)*; see nuts.
>
> nuts (adj.)
> "crazy," 1846, from earlier be nutts upon "be very fond of" (1785), which is possibly from nuts (plural noun) "any source of pleasure" (1610s), from nut (q.v.). **Sense influenced probably by metaphoric application of nut to "head"** (1846, as in to be off one's nut "be insane," 1860). Nuts as a derisive retort is attested from 1931.

I think that the expressions health nut has a derogatory meaning:

[Health nut](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=health%20nut)

> A health nut is a person who is obsessed about his/her health.
> "Health nuts are going to feel stupid someday, lying in hospitals dying of nothing."

while *sports nut* is more neutral:

[Sports nut](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=a%20sports%20nut):

> A Sports fan. Someone who loves to watch sports.
> I love to watch sports. I go to soccer games all the time. I'm a sports nut.

Comment: +1 It's a bit ironic that the more active endeavor (health activity obsession) is more pejorative than the couch potato counterpart (sports fanatic).

Comment: Your examples for each sound totally contrived and only demonstrate the derogatory/neutral meaning *by design*. I think the phrases themselves are both neutral, but can vary pos/neg with context or tone of voice.

Comment: @OlliFord - The examples I show are taken from the Urban Dictionary an I chose them because I think they represent what both expression essentially mean. On the other hand, why use 'nut' which has a clear connotation of something 'crazy' or 'uncommon' rather then a more neutral term like 'health conscious' or 'health fan'? The tone used or the context can of course add to their meaning a more positive or negative connotation.

Comment: "Health nut" doesn't always carry a derogatory connotation. Some people would even describe themselves as "health nuts", just to mean that they're obsessed with health and fitness. This is not always a negative thing.

Comment: Which raises the question. Are there any other "nuts" besides health and sports?

Answer (score 3):

I read that the probable derivation is that head became nut, because of the physical resemblance.  Then "off his head" meaning crazy became "off his nut" which got shortened to nut.

Now that nut means crazy, most other usages "sports nut" derive from that.

EDIT: Confirmation that Etymology Online agrees with this on this post:

[How did the phrase "are you nuts" come about?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23963/how-did-the-phrase-are-you-nuts-come-about)

Comment: Are you implying that I am unreliable?  For shame!

Comment: Do you think *health nut* is derogatory/neutral/positive?

Comment: I think that health/sports nut have both been jokingly positive since inception.  While some try and make it derogatory, I think both fields accept it as positive aside from extreme cases.

Comment: I asked because once I offered *health nut* as an answer, and someone commented that it was [derogative](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115343/how-do-you-describe-a-person-who-loves-everything-natural-when-it-comes-to-healt/115348#comment235120_115348) and inappropriate

Comment: You should have asked **that** person for references and citations about it being derogatory.

Comment: I was young and innocent then :)

Comment: The missing quotation marks in the link was driving me nuts, I had to edit the post.

Answer (score 2):

### The *case* of "Health nut" and "Sports nut"

I debated whether to edit my findings in my question or ask a separate question altogether. If I included the graphs in my question, it would seem I was less interested in the etymology and usage of *nut=insane* than I really am.

Anyway, after some reflection I am confident in stating that today *health nut* and *sports nut* are not derogatory terms, despite [Urban Dictionary's](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=health%20nut) sardonic entry. Although I can imagine someone labelling a person who is careful with their diet and does regular exercise as being a *health nut*, I feel that ***health freak*** is more pejorative and describes a health obsession taken to extreme more accurately. Generally speaking, the current [*health craze*](http://www.unc.edu/~andrewsr/ints092/weikel.html), which started in the 70s, has continued to gain momentum and anyone who cares about their physical health (and appearance) is usually admired.

> Television began bringing teams [American football and basketball] from across the country into the spotlight. The exposure of sports continually grew, as did their popularity. Individual sports like tennis and jogging took off (Strasser & Becklund). The health craze swept the nation [...] . By the end of the 70s sports were becoming a marketing tool and industry on a national scale.

Of course I realize that the term  *sports nut* may mean the person enjoys watching sports from the comfort of his/her couch, but the term doesn't preclude the possibility of them actually *doing* sports. In conclusion the term *nut* is used to denote someone's passion and enthusiasm rather than allude to their mental health.

To compare usage I added the colloquial terms: sports/health *nut*, sports/health *freak*, and sports/health *crazy*. The first chart shows a constant rise in popularity for *health nut*. [AmEng Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=health%20nut,health%20freak,health%20crazy,sports%20freak,sports%20nut,sports%20crazy&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,health%20nut;,c0;.t1;,health%20freak;,c0;.t1;,sports%20freak;,c0;.t1;,sports%20nut;,c0;.t1;,sports%20crazy;,c0)

[image]

But if we use the same identical terms in the British English corpus, the results are quite surprising. *Health freak* surpasses *health nut* and the terms *sports crazy* and *sports freak* are non-existent! Why? I can only surmise that the general British public is more cynical and less sports/fitness/health oriented than their cousins across the pond.

[image]
[BrEng Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=health%20nut,health%20freak,health%20crazy,sports%20freak,sports%20nut,sports%20crazy&year_start=1960&year_end=2005&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,health%20nut;,c0;.t1;,health%20freak;,c0;.t1;,sports%20nut;,c0)

*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* by Eric Partridge (this 8th edition is dated 1982) confirms that "health/sport nut" has positive connotations.

[image]

Comment: Fascinating information. Thanks for posting it.